# How to read the string from an .INI file and then read that string from a text file and print the entire line using Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I have written a code as below.

```
if(sections=='EQUAL'):

  print "Equal"
  for name in config.items('EQUAL'):

    s=str(name[0]) 
    print s
    for each_file in list_of_files:

      if each_file.endswith('_abc.TXT'):
        f=open(each_file)
           for line in f:
             if(re.search("s", line)):
           print line
                       `txt=line.split(":")
                        s1=str(txt[1])
                        s1=s1.lstrip()
                        s1=s1.strip('\t\r\n')
                        n1=str(name[1])
                        if(s1==n1):
                            print "Yes!!"`
```

The code is reading from an INI file which has a section defined as EQUAL. The value inside the EQUAL section (considered as s in the code) can keep changing so we cant keep it constant in our code.

It has to search for s in the _abc.txt file and if it finds s then it has to print that line.

```
The **output** of the above code is:

Equal
Number of failed students(abc)
```

Inside INI file I have :

```
[EQUAL]

Number of failed students(abc):5657
```

The _abc.txt file will be like:

```
Number of failed students(abc)                                 :5647
Number of passed students(dce)                                  : 9695
total number of students                                         :15000
average marks of each student                                    :600
```

The code should check whether the string value present in .ini file is equal in _abc.txt file

Comment: Where is `list_of_files` defined?

Comment: list_of_files is a name of variable which is reading the names of all files in a directory and then we are searching _abc.txt in all the file names and opening the same.

Comment: Can you post the structure of `_abc.TXT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this-**

```
if(sections == 'EQUAL'):
    print "Equal"
    for name in config.items('EQUAL'):
        s = str(name[0]) + ':' + str(name[1])
        print s
        for each_file in list_of_files:
            if each_file.endswith('_abc.TXT'):
                f = open(each_file)
                for line in f:
                    if s in line: #checks for the presence of a substring in a string
                        print line
```

**Note:** .ini files should be of the following format-

```
name = value
```

Comment: Equal
Number of failed students
i got this output..its not printing the entire line.it should print :number of failed students: 5647

Comment: @nithya But the value **5647** is in the **.ini** file, right? how would that be printed when you have not specified that?

Comment: also show us how does your **_abc.txt** file look like

Comment: its not printing the value.i got the same result as before.

Comment: @nithya which value do you want? the one in the **.ini** file? If you want some value from the **_abc.txt** file please show us the file structure

Comment: the code will first read the equal section in .ini file and then it will have to read the number of failed students(abc) : 5647 from the _abc.txt file.5647 is jus a sample value.its not constant.

Comment: @nithya then why do you have `Number of failed students(abc):005657` in the **.ini** file? Also try printing the value of `list_of_files`. That section of the code is not getting executed I think.

Comment: Number of failed students(abc)                                    :5647
Number of passed students(dce)                                     : 9695
total number of students                                           :15000
average marks of each student                                      :600
sample of _abc.txt file is shown above

Comment: @nithya Did you check the contents of `list_of_files`??

Comment: @nithya please include the stacktrace. I don't see why that wouldn't work. It works for me.

Comment: _abc.txt is present inside a directory.so i referred it as list_of_files._abc.txt file will be opened and also number of failed students which is in ini file is read from the txt fileand printed.why is it not printing the entire line?entire line means the value

Comment: @nithya Is `_abc.txt` being opened? Have you checked that? because the rest of the code works fine on my side

Comment: @nithya do keep in mind that the **endswith** function is case-sensitive, so `endswith('_abx.TXT')` and `endswith('_abc.txt')` are not the same. I think that should solve your problem. Also, is there a reason why you are using `endswith`? Why not `if each_file == '_abc.txt'`??

Comment: ya i checked it._abc.txt file is being opened.

Comment: please post your full code along with the exact contents of your **.ini** and the **_abc.txt** file by editing the question

Comment: 'if(re.search("Number of failed students", line)):
           print line'     i deleted the value 005657 from .ini file and executed.it prints the value.but wen i use s it dosent print

Comment: @nithya the variable `s` contains `Number of failed students(abc)` and you are comparing it with `re.search("Number of failed students", line)`. you have supplied different strings so maybe your **_abc.txt** does not have **(abc)** at the end of **Number of failed students**

Comment: i have checkd the _abc.txt file.it has (abc) at the end of the string.the value of s is not constant.it will keep changing.

Comment: can we compare the value present in .ini file with the _abc.txt file?

Comment: @nithya you edited the question but forgot to add your **_abc.txt** file to it.

Comment: @nithya BTW, try replacing `Number of failed students(abc):5657` with `Number of failed students(abc) = 5657` in your **.ini** file ;) read this- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Format

Comment: _abc.txt file format i have included in my question.

Comment: i tried replacing.now how will it compare with the .txt file?how to check the value of number of failed students(abc):5647 present in .ini file is equal to the number of failed students(abc) present in .txt file?

Comment: @nithya just concat the **{name, value}** pair and search, `s = str(name[0]) + ':' + str(name[1])`

Comment: @nithya Ah finally! Lemme update the answer so that the question can be closed.

Comment: @nithya please accept the answer if this solves your problem so that the question can be closed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

`if(re.search("s", line)):`

To:

`if(re.search(s, line)):`

To search the real string and not `"s"`

Also fix the indention at the last `print` to be under the if statment

Comment: hi,i checked this code its giving the same result. i have to get the value of s as well.

Comment: `s` is your search string, try to `print s, line` to see the lines, also pay attention that you are searching for `Number of failed students (abc)` and at your `.ini` file you have `Number of failed students(abc)` without the space.

Comment: iam searching Number of failed students(abc) without the space.same as it is  in ini file.

Comment: Look at those lines `s=str(name[0])  print sz` you have a space at the result `Number of failed students (abc)`,Since you are struggling with debug my suggestion is try to break your code to segments and debug each part.